# How do you build jsonpath checking for non-existence of property in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, jsonpath

I can query for a JSON object with a property matching some value like so:

```
jsonb_path_query(p.blah::jsonb, '$[*] ? (@.fruit == "banana") ')
```

but I can't figure out how to check for a JSON object where the property is not defined. this:

```
jsonb_path_query(p.blah::jsonb, '$[*] ? (!(@ ? fruit))')
```

gives me "unexpected IDENT_P", and this:

```
jsonb_path_query(p.blah::jsonb, '$[*] ? (!(@ ? "fruit"))')
```

gives me 'unexpected STRING_P'

Comment: The column should have been defined as `jsonb` from the start. That would avoid casting it each time you want to do something with it.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out:

```
'$[*] ? (!exists(@.fruit))'
```

Comment: Thanks. It works almost like JavaScript.